Parallelizing raster file generation in ArcGIS Pro
I am currently working on an a Python version of ArcGIS-Based Nitrogen Load Estimation Toolbox Developed for ArcGIS Pro called ArcNLET. I have a question regarding the Parallel Processing Factor (Environment setting) in ArcGIS Pro.
Does this factor control all possible parallelization for the Python script?
Is it possible to create functions that parallelize the creation of the raster files?
ArcNLET is a toolbox that creates raster files for the plumes of contaminant from septic tanks. Currently it generates each plume sequentially and the Python script I am using has the parallel processing environmental factor to the highest setting. I am familiarizing myself with the ins and outs of the scripts I just don't know if the environment factor supersedes all.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Unfortunately, I suspect you're overestimating the benefits than can accrue from this environment setting. I suggest you perform some benchmarking to determine the exact benefit in your context.

If you have set it to say 100% then ONLY the tools that honour it will parallelize their operation. It does not parallelize python. You don't really say HOW your rasters are created, so for example if your raster is created from a polygon to raster tool, then studying the environment settings of that tool you will see that it does not honour parallel processing factor.
Suggest you read the Parallel processing with Spatial Analyst help page.
